# Dealing with resource closure when rethrowing an exception

Tags: c++, exception-handling

I would like a review and recommendations for improvement of the code below.  I want to allow an exception to be handled by the caller, so I am rethrowing it.  But I have resources to close.  So I have the resource closing code duplicated in both the try and the catch blocks.  Is there a better way to do this?

```
const string HTTPopotamus::GET(void) {
  HINTERNET  hSession = NULL, 
      hConnect = NULL,
      hRequest = NULL;
    try {
        hSession = this->open();
        hConnect = this->connect(hSession);
        hRequest = this->openRequest(hConnect);
        this->sendRequest(hRequest);
        this->receiveResponse(hRequest);
        string strData = this->readData(hRequest);
        /* Close any open resources. */
        if( hRequest ) WinHttpCloseHandle( hRequest );
        if( hConnect ) WinHttpCloseHandle( hConnect );
        if( hSession ) WinHttpCloseHandle( hSession );
        return strData;
    } catch (const ExceptionCyclOps& e) {
        /* Close any open resources. */
        if( hRequest ) WinHttpCloseHandle( hRequest );
        if( hConnect ) WinHttpCloseHandle( hConnect );
        if( hSession ) WinHttpCloseHandle( hSession );
        throw;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that your code would benefit dramatically from use of [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAII). To illustrate, let's assume the existence of an `HTTPConnection` class that opens an appropriate connection in its constructor and closes it at destruction. The code would look more like the following:

```
const string HTTPopotamus::GET(void) {
    HTTPConnection conn(/*connection parameters here*/);

    conn.sendRequest(/*request parameters here*/);
    conn.waitForResponse(HTTP_REQUEST_TIMEOUT);

    return this->readData(hRequest);
}
```

This approach is more elegant and clear and explains itself with no need for comments. Any exception thrown, such as exceptions that represent a failed connection or a timeout event would be propagated to the caller while the `HTTPConnection` object would still be destroyed properly.